# Android: map view doesn't work

Tags: android, google-maps

in my Android App I have add a map activity whit the Android Studio procedure (add-> new activity -> Google -> Map). I have followed this example: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start#step_2_install_the_google_play_services_sdk.

But if I open the map activity, it's strange, I see only a map whit the Google logo but completely empty (I attach a screenshot). And I don't see any connection or key error message. Why?

PS I have only added the "import com.mycompany.myapp.R" row in the activity java file, because in the original file create with the automatic procedure, I see all "R" in that file in red as an error.

Summarizing:

1) I have add a map activity whit the Android Studio automatic procedure
2) I have followed the procedure and copied the key in my app (I don't see any key or certificate error message)
3) I have only add the row about import com.mycompany.myapp.R
4) If I test on my real device, I see a blank map.

Thank!

Code of activity:

```html
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.mycompany.myapp.Views.myFragmentMap" />
```

Code of java file related to the activity:

```html
package com.mycompany.myapp.Views;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

//I have added only this one!
import com.mycompany.myapp.R;

public class myFragmentMap extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_myapp_map);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

Google maps api file, in which I have copied my key:

```html
<resources>

    <string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">
        AIza.... (and the correct code imported from Google)
    </string>
</resources>
```

And this is the screen of the activity
[image]

Comment: Check your logs, there will be an error regarding the API key.

Comment: just launch after sometime it may be downloading playstore update

Answer (score 0):

Did you run the application right after installing the Google Play services SDK?

Daniel is right, you can check the logs for error that might be related to API key.

> [*Get a Google Maps API key*](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start#step_4_get_a_google_maps_api_key)
>
> Your application needs an API key to access the Google Maps servers. The type of key you need is a Key for Android applications. The key is free. You can use it with any of your applications that call the Google Maps Android API, and it supports an unlimited number of users.
>
> Use the credentials provided in the google_maps_api.xml file that Android Studio created for you:
>
> 1. Copy the credentials provided in the `google_maps_api.xml` file.
> 2. Go to the [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/) in your browser.
> 3. Use the copied credentials to add your app to an existing API key or to create a new API key. For more details, see the [complete process](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup).

Following all steps from 1-7 will give you the basic working google maps app. I hope it helps. Also here a previous [Google Map on Android do not load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26171251/google-map-on-android-do-not-load?rq=1) SO that you may relate your experience

Answer (score 0):

I got similar issue. Try delete your app and reinstall again.